# How to test whether a lazy loaded child collection has been loaded

Tags: entity-framework-6

Suppose I have users with tags being lazy loaded:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

If I get a user this way, I know that the tags aren't loaded:

```
User myUser;
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    myUser = context.Users.Find(4);
}
```

How do I test the `Tags` collection presence outside of the `using` clause?

```
if (myUser.Tags == null) // throws an ObjectDisposedException
```

I could use a try/catch but there must be a better way.

Comment: @Tuco I don't want to load them, just test whether they are loaded. If I have several different ways to load that entity (some with, others without `Include`), some external code should be able to adapt to the available child collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to be able to do a non virtual call (similar to when you do `base.Something` in a derived class) to the class property getter. Since there is no way to do that with pure C# or reflection, I've ended up with the following helper method which utilizes `System.Reflection.Emit` LCG (lightweight code generation) to emit `Call` IL instruction instead of the normal `Callvirt`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static class Utils
{
    public static TValue GetClassValue<TSource, TValue>(this TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector)
        where TSource : class

    {
        Func<TSource, TValue> getValue = null;
        if (source.GetType() != typeof(TSource))
        {
            var propertyAccessor = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (propertyAccessor != null)
            {
                var propertyInfo = propertyAccessor.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    var getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
                    if (getMethod != null && getMethod.IsVirtual)
                    {
                        var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(TValue), new[] { typeof(TSource) }, typeof(Utils), true);
                        var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, getMethod, null);
                        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                        getValue = (Func<TSource, TValue>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TSource, TValue>));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (getValue == null)
            getValue = selector.Compile();
        return getValue(source);
    }
}
```

It can be used for both single and collection type navigation properties like this:

```
if (myUser.GetClassValue(x => x.Tags) == null)
```

Comment: Impressive. So it returns the actual value if it has been loaded and null otherwise? Can you estimate the cost of this call compared to a try/catch getting the value?

Comment: Yes - you can try it :) And yes, it's costly, so if the performance is concern, then it would need some delegate caching.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a naive try/catch, not sure about the performance compared to the other answer:

```
using System;

public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
{
    public static bool IsCollectionLoaded<TSource, TValue>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
        where TSource : class
    {
        try
        {
            return (selector(source) != null);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
if (myUser.IsCollectionLoaded(x => x.Tags))
```